# Loop not producing plots in order of factor level R

Tags: r

I am trying to use Markdown to produce a report which includes top 10 diagnoses by week. I want a plot to display for each week in order of the week numbers (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11). However, when I use the loop, the plots output in random order (10, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 4, 11). How do I get the plots to print starting with Week 3?

````
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(week = factor(week, levels = c("W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7", "W8", "W9", "W10", "W11"))) 
    
    week_names <- unique(df$week)
    
    # for each name ("weeks") in week_names, create and print the plot
    for (weeks in week_names) {
      
      top_10_dx_week <- df %>% 
        filter(week == weeks) %>% 
        group_by(category) %>% 
        summarize(
          count = n()
        ) %>% 
        arrange(-count) %>% 
        slice(1:10)

      
      top_10_dx_plot <- 
        ggplot(data = top_10_dx_week,
               mapping =
                 aes(x= category),
                     y= count,
                     fill = category)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        geom_text(aes(label=count), hjust = -0.3, size=2.5) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.1))) +
        ggtitle("Top 10 Categories:", weeks) +
        coord_flip()
      
      print(top_10_dx_plot)
    }  
    ```
````

Comment: Not random order, alphanumeric. Try `df <- df %>% mutate(week = factor(week, levels = c("W03", "W04", "W05", "W06", "W07", "W08", "W09", "W10", "W11")))`

Comment: I tried that...still not working :(

Comment: It worked on the test vector I created so I need to see your data. Please use `dput()` to provide a sample of your df and post the result to your question to make your issue reproducible.